# In object oriented analysis and design what is the role of message?

Tags: oop, object, analysis

In Object oriented programming objects communicate by passing messages, sometimes these messages can also have arguments.

```
I.e. A Student object can send a message to a School object asking for a list of public holidays.
```

My question is how these messages are different then traditional class methods? are they both same thing? and how do we show them in UML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such a thing as 'message passing', you can read about it on [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) but from the text you quote, I would guess they just mean a method call. Can't say more without more context.

Comment: Most of the docs only represent theory which I am familiar with. In some UML notations messages are shown with italic fonts and methods are shown as normal fonts. This is where it gets confusing, if messages are normal methods and are same things why two different notations?

Comment: Good question, my UML knowledge is not good enough to definitively answer this, but from the page here http://users.skynet.be/averkeyn/computer/uml.html it seems that italicized means abstract methods. Would that make sense?